# Spring security filter not firing up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

My authentication filters are not firing up under request.

I have 2 security configurations, one for the login endpoint only, authenticating with the `AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter` filter, and another one for the other endpoints, authenticating with the `AuthenticationFromTokenFilter` filter.

I expect the `attemptAuthentication` method of the filters to be called but they are not.

Is there any point in prefering to authenticate the credentials and create the token, in a filter rather than in the login controller ?

The login controller is present for now, but it should not exist as its job should be done by the filter.

I set them up each in a security configuration:

```java
@EnvProd
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.user.rest.security", "com.thalasoft.user.rest.filter" })
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public class CredentialsConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        public AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter() throws Exception {
            AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter = new AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter();
            authenticationFromCredentialsFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
            return authenticationFromCredentialsFilter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/users/login")
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFromCredentialsFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/users/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public class TokenConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter;

        @Autowired
        private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        private SimpleCORSFilter simpleCORSFilter;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .csrf().disable();

            http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            http
                .headers()
                .cacheControl().disable()
                .frameOptions().disable();

            http
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint);

            http 
                .addFilterBefore(simpleCORSFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

            http
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFromTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

            http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFromTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole(UserDomainConstants.ROLE_ADMIN)
                .anyRequest().authenticated();    
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the two filters:

```java
public class AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Autowired
    CredentialsService credentialsService;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            CredentialsResource credentialsResource = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(),
                    CredentialsResource.class);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(credentialsService.authenticate(credentialsResource));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        tokenAuthenticationService.addTokenToResponseHeader(response, authentication);
    }

}

public class AuthenticationFromTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        tokenAuthenticationService.authenticate(request);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(tokenAuthenticationService.authenticate(request));
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    }

}
```

Here is an example of a login request that should be captured by the `AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter` filter in the security configuration, but is not, and thus is allowed to proceed to the controller and give a response with a `201` status:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:8080/api/users/login" -X POST -d "{ \"email\" : \"xxxxxx@yahoo.se\", \"password\" : \"xxxxx\" }"
HTTP/1.1 201 
Cache-Control: no-store
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MzQwNTE5MjYsInN1YiI6Im1pdHRpcHJvdmVuY2VAeWFob28uc2UifQ.LOJvr5jWouWsLN_Pinlr_F5dntON45hwpUFVmXD2Xqo
Location: http://localhost:8080/api/users/1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 05 Aug 2018 05:32:07 GMT


{"firstname":"Stephane","lastname":"Eybert","email":"xxxxx@yahoo.se","confirmedEmail":false,"password":"bWl0dGlwcm92ZW5jZUB5YWhvby5zZTptaWduZXQxYjE4ZDQ5MS00ZGRhLTQxZWYtYWM5ZS04N2Y5ODk=","workPhone":null,"userRoles":[{"role":"ROLE_ADMIN","id":1}],"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"},"roles":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/roles"}},"id":1}[stephane@stephane-ThinkPad-X201 user-rest (master)]
```

Am I right to expect the login request to be firing up the `AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter` filter ? With the filter doing the authentication and responding with a token ? And the login controller not being called at all ?

Here is another example of a password change request that should be captured by the `AuthenticationFromTokenFilter` filter in the security configuration, but is not, and thus is allowed to proceed to the controller and give a response with a `200` status:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/password" -X PUT -d "\"xxxxx\""
HTTP/1.1 200 
Cache-Control: no-store
Location: http://localhost:8080/api/users/1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 04 Aug 2018 20:23:17 GMT

{"firstname":"Stephane","lastname":"Eybert","email":"xxxx@yahoo.se","confirmedEmail":false,"password":"bWl0dGlwcm92ZW5jZUB5YWhvby5zZTptaWduZXRhYTA4OTNiZS0yMzZlLTQ3ZjktOTE2Ny0zOTU0NTY=","workPhone":null,"userRoles":[{"role":"ROLE_ADMIN","id":1}],"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"},"roles":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/roles"}},"id":1}
```

And what about using a `CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider` instead of a `AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter` filter for the login request ? Is that still possible under `Spring Boot 2.0.3` ?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

With the authentication provider being:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    CredentialsService credentialsService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return credentialsService.authenticate(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        boolean value = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
        return value;
    }

}
```

UPDATE: I also tried this configuration but it didn't change anything to the issue:

```
public AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter() throws Exception {
    AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter = new AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter();
    authenticationFromCredentialsFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    authenticationFromCredentialsFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/users/login"));
    return authenticationFromCredentialsFilter;
}

public AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter() throws Exception {
    AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter = new AuthenticationFromTokenFilter();
    authenticationFromTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    authenticationFromTokenFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));
    return authenticationFromTokenFilter;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.headers().cacheControl().disable().frameOptions().disable();

    http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint);

    http.addFilterBefore(simpleCORSFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http.antMatcher("/api/**")
    .addFilterBefore(authenticationFromCredentialsFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .addFilterBefore(authenticationFromTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/users/login").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole(UserDomainConstants.ROLE_ADMIN)
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filters extend `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and this filter by default is only applied for URL `/login`, see [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html):

> This filter by default responds to the URL `/login`.

If you want to change the default to another URL, see [`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#setFilterProcessesUrl`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#setFilterProcessesUrl-java.lang.String-):

> Sets the URL that determines if authentication is required

Your modified code:

```java
public AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter() throws Exception {
    AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter = new AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter();
    authenticationFromCredentialsFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    authenticationFromCredentialsFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/users/login");
    return authenticationFromCredentialsFilter;
}
```

If you want to use a pattern, see [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html):

> This filter will intercept a request and attempt to perform authentication from that request if the request matches the `setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(RequestMatcher)`.

Your modified code:

```java
public AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter() throws Exception {
    AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter= new AuthenticationFromTokenFilter();
    authenticationFromTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    authenticationFromTokenFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**");
    return authenticationFromTokenFilter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could finally have the filters fire up and each for their own requests under a `Spring Boot 2` environment.

The credentials filter fires up upon a login request to the `/users/login` endpoint.

The token filter fires up upon any request except the login request.

To assign a url pattern to a filter, the filter had to extend the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` class. And the two filters extend that class. The pattern is specified in their constructor.

The credentials filter is:

```java
public class AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Autowired
    CredentialsService credentialsService;

    public AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter(final RequestMatcher requestMatcher) {
        super(requestMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            CredentialsResource credentialsResource = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(),
                    CredentialsResource.class);
            return credentialsService.authenticate(credentialsResource);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        tokenAuthenticationService.addTokenToResponseHeader(response, authentication);
    }

}
```

Note that on successful authentication, the filter chain is not pursued, that is there is no such call to `filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);` because there is no need to hit a controller endpoint, since the response is already sent back with the token.

It is explicitly instantiated with a `@Bean` annotation so as to specify the matcher pattern:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter() throws Exception {
    AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter = new AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/login", RequestMethod.POST.name()));
    authenticationFromCredentialsFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    return authenticationFromCredentialsFilter;
}
```

The token filter is:

```java
public class AuthenticationFromTokenFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public AuthenticationFromTokenFilter(final RequestMatcher requestMatcher) {
        super(requestMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        return tokenAuthenticationService.authenticate(request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
            FilterChain filterChain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    }

}
```

It is explicitly instantiated with a `@Bean` annotation so as to specify the matcher pattern:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter() throws Exception {
    AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter = new AuthenticationFromTokenFilter(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/login", RequestMethod.POST.name())));
    authenticationFromTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    return authenticationFromTokenFilter;
}
```

Contrary to the previous credentials filter, this filter needs to be explicitly specified in the configuration:

```java
http
.addFilterBefore(authenticationFromTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

To avoid this filter being fired up twice in the filters chain, a bean instructs Spring Boot not to automatically inject it:

```java
@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean<AuthenticationFromTokenFilter> disableAutoRegistration(final AuthenticationFromTokenFilter filter) {
    final FilterRegistrationBean<AuthenticationFromTokenFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<AuthenticationFromTokenFilter>(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```

Note that on successful authentication, the filter chain is pursued, that is there is a call to `filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);` because there is a need to hit a controller endpoint, after successful authentication.

The full configuration is:

```java
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = PackageBeanNameGenerator.class, basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.user.rest.security",
"com.thalasoft.user.rest.service", "com.thalasoft.user.rest.filter" })
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleCORSFilter simpleCORSFilter;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter authenticationFromCredentialsFilter = new AuthenticationFromCredentialsFilter(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/login", RequestMethod.POST.name()));
        authenticationFromCredentialsFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationFromCredentialsFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationFromTokenFilter authenticationFromTokenFilter = new AuthenticationFromTokenFilter(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/login", RequestMethod.POST.name())));
        authenticationFromTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationFromTokenFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<AuthenticationFromTokenFilter> disableAutoRegistration(final AuthenticationFromTokenFilter filter) {
        final FilterRegistrationBean<AuthenticationFromTokenFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<AuthenticationFromTokenFilter>(filter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .logout().disable();

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint);

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(simpleCORSFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

        http
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationFromTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/error").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/users/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole(UserDomainConstants.ROLE_ADMIN)
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

Also, note that the is not being used at all in this Spring Boot configuration:

```java
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    CredentialsService credentialsService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return credentialsService.authenticate(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }

}
```

I wonder where it could fit and how it could replace the credentials filter... but that is another story.